Using the Galois Group of a Cyclotomic Field to Invert Roots of Unity
If we consider the $n$th Cyclotomic Number Field $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta) \cong \mathbb{Q}[X]/\langle \phi_{n}(x) \rangle$, where $\zeta = e^{i2 \pi/n}$ is primitive, we see that the nth roots of unity form a multiplicative group. In this setting, we see that raising $\zeta$ to any power between 0 and $n-1$ gives us another root. This means, by way of example, that $\zeta^a$ is a root, but so is $\zeta^{-a}$. We also have the result that for this field, Gal( $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta))/ \mathbb{Q})\cong  \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}^*$. Since the group action can be interpreted as a permutation of the roots of unity (and their inverses), is there a way to specifically exploit the group action to construct a formula or recipe to compute the inverse of a given root of unity?

By "inverse" do you mean the reciprocal of a root of unity? The reciprocal of a root of unity is the same as its complex conjugate, and complex conjugation is an element of the Galois group (it corresponds to $-1\in(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^*$).

Yes, by inverse I mean the reciprocal. Thank you

The reciprocal of any root of unity is the same as its complex conjugate. Moreover, complex conjugation is an element of the Galois group Gal$(\Bbb Q(\zeta)/\Bbb Q)$: it corresponds to $-1\in(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^*$.
